# Jquery adds "?" on URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

hi i have this ajax function

```
mainUrl = "http://someURL/POSMobileConnector/";
    parameter = "Event Materials";
    servEntity = "Product/"
    console.log("test");

    $.ajax({
        url: mainUrl + servEntity + 'loaditembycategory/',
        type: "GET",
        data: parameter ,
        dataType:'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        ProcessData:false,
        //username:"admin",
        //password:"admin",
        //beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        //   xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", cred/*"Basic " + encodeBase64(credentials)*/);
        //},
        success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
                ServiceSucceeded(msg);      
        },
        error: function(error){
              console.log(error);        
        }   
      });
```

My Question is when i look at firebug. the url result is http://url/service/Product/loaditembycategory/?Event%20Materials. Now i want to remove the "?" part because the right url is to be http://url/service/Product/Event%20Materials only.

Comment: what are you trying to do, or more specifically what is the problem? Why would "?" confuse when it is a GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then add it to the URL

```
 url: mainUrl + servEntity + 'loaditembycategory/' + Param,
```

The data param is for GET or POST params only.

Comment: oh. can you explain further what would be the use of data field?

Comment: oh sorry, i haven't refreshed it. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

The `data:` parameter is put in the query string.
It sounds like you don't want a query string, so you shouldn't use the `data:` parameter at all.

Instead, concatenate the URL string directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    url: mainUrl + servEntity + 'loaditembycategory/' + Param,
    type: "GET",
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  //...
  url: mainUrl + servEntity + 'loaditembycategory/' + encodeURIComponent(Param)
  //...
});
```